# среднедневное значение

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы:

```
Tab1
ID|Name
1|  Иванов
2|  Петров
3|  Сидоров

Tab2
TransDate|RcvID|SndID|Quantity
11.02.2012  1   2     100
12.02.2012  1   3     150
13.02.2012  3   1     300
14.02.2012  2   1     50
```

,где

RcvID - ид получателя (из 1й табл)

SndID - ид отправителя (из 1й табл)

Quantity - кол-во денег

Нужно посчитать средний дневной **оборот** для Иванова, Петрова и Сидорова

Не много не понятно, оборот же, это только приход, кто с экономикой дружит? Если да, то нужно посчитать среднее арифметическое AVG (Quantity) по RcvID?

Comment: проблема то ваша в чем?

Comment: думаю вы всё правильно поняли, простейшая задачка на получение среднего значения, где в where вы указываете `RcvID=1`

Comment: Эммм... по-моему, при расчёте оборота не должно учитываться направление движения. Только голый факт участия субъекта в операции и её сумма. И по субъектам 2 и 3 - следует уточнить, требуется средний оборот за весь период или только за те дни, когда проводились операции.

Comment: @Akina да, не должно учитываться направление движения. 2 и 3 так же как и 1й

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вроде так:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT RcvID id, Quantity FROM tab2
          UNION ALL
          SELECT SndID, Quantity FROM tab2 ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT DATEDIFF(MAX(TransDate), MIN(TransDate)) + 1 duration
          FROM tab2 ),
SELECT tab1.name, SUM(cte1.Quantity/cte2.duration) avg_turnover
FROM tab1, cte1, cte2
WHERE tab1.id = cte1.id
GROUP BY tab1.name
```